# Formatting float values

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, floating-point

This is probably a stupid question but anyway.

I wan the number I set on my label to be formated nicely like this 20,000,000 .
How do I do this ?

For now I've set the number of decimal points to 0 so I just get the whole number without any places.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", slider.value];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following formatter:

```
-(void)setCurrencyFormat
{

    NSNumberFormatter *CurrencyFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
    [CurrencyFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    label.text= [CurrencyFormat stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:billAmountInDouble]];

    NSString *st1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[CurrencyFormat stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:individualTaxInDouble]]];
    label.text=st1;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs for NSNumberFormatter - you can do pretty much everything with that.